# Why does the date doesn't match with what I have inserted into the database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I tried to display the `sqlcommand` after I saved into the database. Everything seemed to work pretty fine, but when I opened my table from TOAD, the dates are wrong.

Here is my sql command:

```
INSERT INTO USERTASK (USERTASKKEY, USERID, TASKKEY, TASKDATE, CREATEDATE, CREATEUSERID)
VALUES (USERTASKSEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'admin2', '1',
        TO_DATE('05-06-2015','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS'),
        TO_DATE('2015-06-16 15:39:42', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS'), 'admin')
```

In my database the date save as:

> 6/20/0016 3:00:00.000000

Here you can see a screenshot with several dates wrong:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the TO_DATE function you have to keep the format. 
The first parameter is the data and the second parameter is the format you are putting it. For example:

```
   to_date('29-Oct-09', 'DD-Mon-YY')
   to_date('10/29/09', 'MM/DD/YY')
   to_date('120109', 'MMDDYY')
   to_date('29-Oct-09', 'DD-Mon-YY HH:MI:SS') 
   to_date('Oct/29/09', 'Mon/DD/YY HH:MI:SS')
   to_date('October.29.2009', 'Month.DD.YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

So if you put `TO_DATE('05-06-2015','yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS')` it tries to convert `05-06-2015` to the format `yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI:SS`

Try with `TO_DATE('05-06-2015','DD/MM/YYYY')`

Comment: so i have to put it as dd/MM/yyyy instead of yyyy/mm/dd?

Comment: You should not use 2 digit year as `YY`, remember the **Y2K Bug**. I case you really like (or have) to use only 2 digits, use `RR` format.